# What 90's made-for-tv movie featured a time-traveling policeman who left his wife a note from the past?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, tv, paradox

I recall watching a made for TV movie in the 90's that takes place in the future about a man who works for a time-travel enforcement agency. At the beginning of the movie he got his wife an old copy of a book she really liked. Despite one of the pages having a tear, it was the best authentic copy he could find and she treasured it. Later on at work, he had to track an escaped criminal in the past (1990's) and most of the movie takes place here as he tracks down and captures the criminal. He was able to stop him, but in the process was no longer able to return to his own time.

Knowing he will never see his wife again, he looks for the exact copy of the book that would later become the gift for his wife and he pulls it off the shelf, accidentally dropping it, causing one of the pages to tear. Knowing this is the book, he writes a farewell love note to her and hides it in the back cover. The movie ends with the wife in the future flipping through her gift and discovering an old faded note in the back, which she reads as she tears up.

Comment: Except for the ending and not being made for TV, this reminded me of Timecop - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timecop

Comment: Yeah, I can see the similarity. I am aware of Timecop but what I am trying to remember is definitely not that movie.

Comment: May be Time Trax also (I think there are two seasons though).

Comment: There was a second Timecop movie.  Straight to video.  Never saw it so I'm tossing it out there as a possibility.

Answer (score 4):

***[Out of Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_Time_(1988_film))*** maybe. It was an NBC failed pilot. Bruce Abbott plays the time traveler, chasing Adam Ant (!) back to 1988 and teaming up with his grandfather or maybe great grandfather, played by Bill Maher (!!). The book element is there.

[It's on YouTube!](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jlzbqJ2mtEo)

Synopsis from Wikipedia:

> A cop from the year 2088 (Abbott) is transported back to 1988 while pursuing a criminal attempting to flee in a time machine, and enlists the aid of his legendary great-grandfather (Maher) in pursuing the crook. However, he finds that his grandfather is not yet the great cop hero/inventor who is revered in the future. Abbott must catch the criminal and help shape his grandfather into the man history recorded.

Comment: Did he leave a note for his wife?

Comment: Yes, he left the note.

Comment: Adam Ant and Bill Maher????  Oh, I'm so watching this.